Datetime-value's time inserted incorrectly in one column but not in another MYSQL
I have a mysql database where im inserting data that has a "StartTime" and "EndTime".
The EndTime is inserted correctly, but the StartTime has its Time sifted by -1 hour.
I checked the Mysql logs that the actual "insert" command has the correct values, but when inspecting the table, or reading to other software the "StartTime" value is -1 hour off. (But not the "EndTime")
This happens on multiple different tables in the same Schema. Allways on the "StartTime"-value.
The date columns are "datetime"-type (both)
What could be causing this?
If I change the values with each other IT STILL changes the "StartTime"-value (that is now going in to the "EndTime"-column), but not the "EndTime"-value (that is now going to the "startTime-colum".)
For example:
INSERT INTO sessionData.sessionHistory (sesConsump,sesTagId,sesDevice,sesStartDate,sesEndDate,sesId,sesCost)
VALUES (37232,'AABBCCDD','Station01','2024-10-14 15:13:11.486+03:00','2024-10-15 07:39:33.742+03:00','U01SQ5QH0JFAJ6SL',558.4819)

This will result in:



sesConsump
sesTagId
sesDevice
sesStartDate
sesEndDate
sesId
sesCost




37232
AABBCCDD
Station01
2024-10-14 14:13:11
2024-10-15 07:39:34
U01SQ5QH0JFAJ6SL
558.4819



Table create statement:
CREATE TABLE `sessionHistory` (
  `sesId` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `sesConsump` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `sesTagId` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sesDevice` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sesStartDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sesEndDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sesCost` float DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`sesId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

Mysql-server global.time_zone = +02:00

What is the result of select now() and the actual time (on your watch)?

Now() gives out 13:04 and my clock is 14:04. In the example I gave the input times are "+03:00" and the server, timezone is "+02:00", my problem with this is that ONLY ONE of the times is incorrect....

What if you insert the same values into both

Any chance that's the original CREATE TABLE statement originally used, but then the table was altered and now either has a different column type for sesStartDate or there's a trigger altering data?

What do you get when you enter just select'2024-10-14 15:13:11.486+03:00'+ INTERVAL 1 DAY,'2024-10-15 07:39:33.742+03:00' + INTERVAL 1 DAY; ? Since you said that swapping the times makes the latter time still go wrong, this should go wrong too. If it doesn't, it might be your column definition.

Are you actually entering the dates as literal strings or where are they coming from?

An interesting feature. Look at the example (https://dbfiddle.uk/Mt6_VYGi). Perhaps the problem is rounding up the time. Value '2024-10-14 15:13:11.499+03:00' is inserted correctly, value '2024-10-14 15:13:11.501+03:00' - without timezone.

This so odd I don't believe we are being told everything. Is there any other tech in play? And where is the server geographically?

It's really weird. Another example (https://sqlfiddle.com/mysql/online-compiler?id=ae8e64aa-ab10-4c1f-a7ca-9cb8d75a8717)

This was really weird indeed... I tried to give all the info I had on the problem. Since the problem seems to be the milliseconds value I may have tested this only with values that have >500 ms on end and <500 on start... And part of the problem was the timezone of the server...

Data type datetime by default is datetime(0). A value of 0 signifies that there is no fractional part.
When literal value like '2024-10-15 07:39:33.742+03:00' converted to datetime, the rounded value differs from the initial value:
'2024-10-15 07:39:33+03:00'<>'2024-10-15 07:39:34+03:00'
In this case no warning or error is given when such rounding occurs,
and timezone part of literal is ignored.
To resolve this behaviour  You can

Use datetime(6) for datetime column with fraction part of seconds.
Or Set 'TIME_TRUNCATE_FRACTIONAL'.
Or Truncate fractional part before insert
'2024-10-15 07:39:33.742+03:00'->'2024-10-15 07:39:33.000+03:00'

Doc
See
Example1. Your case.
create table test (id int,first datetime DEFAULT NULL
  , second datetime DEFAULT NULL, third datetime DEFAULT NULL);
insert into test values
 (1,'2024-10-15 10:00:00.123000+02:00'
   ,'2024-10-15 11:00:00.499000+02:00'
   ,'2024-10-15 11:00:00.501000+02:00')
;
select * from test;




id
first
second
third




1
2024-10-15 08:00:00
2024-10-15 09:00:00
2024-10-15 11:00:01



Example2. All right:
create table test2 (id int,first datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL
  , second datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL, third datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL);
insert into test2 values
 (1,'2024-10-15 10:00:00.123000+02:00'
   ,'2024-10-15 11:00:00.499000+02:00'
   ,'2024-10-15 11:00:00.501000+02:00')
;
select * from test2;




id
first
second
third




1
2024-10-15 08:00:00.123000
2024-10-15 09:00:00.499000
2024-10-15 09:00:00.501000



Example 3. All right:
SET @@sql_mode = sys.list_add(@@sql_mode, 'TIME_TRUNCATE_FRACTIONAL');

create table test3 (id int,first datetime DEFAULT NULL
  , second datetime DEFAULT NULL, third datetime DEFAULT NULL);
insert into test3 values
 (1,'2024-10-15 10:00:00.123000+02:00'
   ,'2024-10-15 11:00:00.499000+02:00'
   ,'2024-10-15 11:00:00.501000+02:00')
;
select * from test3;




id
first
second
third




1
2024-10-15 08:00:00
2024-10-15 09:00:00
2024-10-15 09:00:00



fiddle

I could reproduce this. Just needed to change the +02 in your examples to +03 (in the inserts). As the Timezone of the server is +02. So basically IF the inserted value is in different timezone than the server AND the inserted datetime-string contains milliseconds THEN the value is sifted IF milliseconds are 500 or over....

This doesn't explain why behaviour changes between two columns with identical type. But, given it's the accepted answer, I presume the diagnostic was wrong in the first place.

@ÁlvaroGonzález, there no difference in behaviour between two columns with identical type. Difference is between values '...:11.486+03:00' and '...:33.742+03:00'.First rounded down, second rounded up. Rounding up the value ignore the time zone in datetime literal value. Setting TIME_TRUNCATE_FRACTIONAL returns the expected behavior. See test 4 and 5 in (dbfiddle.uk/LsWXJOSj).

@ValNik Yes, that's why I say that diagnostic was wrong: it isn't "it depends on the column" but "it depends on the value".

Yes, thanks. A good explanation.
